# 21 matchsticks # of possible games

Tags: recursion, math, combinatorics

I am sure everyone is familiar with the famous 21 matchsticks game where each person picks up 1,2 or 3 matches and the last person to pick up a match loses.

Let's simplify the game and assume that it is only possible to pick 1 or 2 matches. My question is, how many games are possible?

I know this is very easy to solve recursively, however, I am trying to come up with a combinatorial solution.

To provide an example, let's reduce 21 to just 4 matches. The number of possible games would be 5. {'MCM', 'MMMM', 'CC', 'CMM', 'MMC'}. Where C represents removing 2 matches and M represents removing a single match.

Comment: You can use the [symbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_method_(combinatorics)) to deduce that the generating function for this combinatorial class is 1/(1-z-z^2-z^3). The number of games corresponds to the coefficient in the power series.

Answer (score 1):

[Symbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_method_(combinatorics)) allows us to deduce that the generating function for this combinatorial class is

```
f(z) = 1/(1 - z - z^2 - z^3)
```

At this point, we can obtain the answer through a power series expansion, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/finding-the-power-series-of-a-rational-function). The coefficient on `z^21` will give the number of possible games in "21 matchsticks" (it might be `233317`).

Looking back, suppose that players were allowed to take one match only. Then, there would be only one possible scenario. For each game length (power of `z`), there is only one game outcome:

```
1/(1 - z) = 1*1 + 1*z + 1*z^2 + 1*z^3 + 1*z^4 + 1*z^5 + ...
```

If players are allowed to take one or two matches, we have multiple scenarios:

```
1/(1 - z - z^2) = 1*1 + 1*z + 2*z^2 + 3*z^3 + 5*z^4 + 8*z^5 + ...
```

The coefficients recover the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) and can be interpreted as a number of integer [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of `n` using only numbers `1` and `2`.

Allowing for taking one, two or three matches leads to the following expansion,

```
1/(1 - z - z^2 - z^3) = 1*1 + 1*z + 2*z^2 + 4*z^3 + 7*z^4 + 13*z^5 + ...
```

which can be found in [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A000073), cordially named the "Tribonacci numbers".

It is possible to arrive at the `233317` answer using pen, paper and a shifted generalization of the [Pascal triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), although I would leave that task to someone else.

---

As an aside, I highly recommend the book "Analytic Combinatorics" by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for their introduction to the symbolic method and beyond.